# How to Limit Fields Returned from $lookup Operation Being Added to a Mongo View

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

In my MongoDB/Node backend setup I am using a combination of pipeline operators via Studio 3T in order to create a particular view. One of the steps in that pipeline involves using the `$lookup` operator to pull in related data from a second collection. This code looks like this:

```
// Stage 3
{
  $lookup: {
    "from": "clients",
    "localField": "client.id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "client"
  }
}
```

To have this drop into the view as an object rather than an array I am then using the `$unwind` operator like so:

```
// Stage 4
{
    $unwind: {
       path : "$client"
    }
}
```

Now this works, in that the info from the corresponding record from the other collection drops into the view exactly where I want it to. However, the issue is, this pulls in all the fields from that corresponding record, when all I actually need is three items from that object; namely the `_id` and `name.first` and `name.last`.

Right now I'm getting something like this:

```
client: {
    _id: someId,
    prop1: value,
    prop2: value,
    prop3: value,
    name: {
      first: value,
      last: value
    }
    prop4: value
}
```

When all I need is this:

```
client: {
    _id: someId,
    name: {
      first: value,
      last: value
    }
}
```

I've looked through the mongo documentation but it's not clear to me how one limits how much of the data is printed to the view from the $lookup operation. Do I need to add some conditional logic to the $lookup operation? Or is there some other operator I should tack on to the pipeline to handle this?

Comment: what about using $project after $lookup stage?

Comment: Okay, got it! Using $project did indeed work. Thanks, @felipsmartins. If you want to write an answer I'll mark it as correct. If not, I'll write out my full answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reshaping" the output document sounds pretty like how using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage of pipeline.

In this case simply adding a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) after [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage and it should to fit for purpose. That is a obvious way to go.
Something like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    /* ... */
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from": "clients",
            "localField": "client.id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "client"
        }
    },
    /* ... */
    {
        $project: {
            client: {
                _id: 1,
                name: 1
            }
        }
    }
];
```